# Spritekit Add nodes without overlapping

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add 20 nodes at random locations on the screen without any of the nodes overlapping. Ive got the adding of the nodes at random locations part but I sill get some that overlap. What I have done so far is: I would be greatful for a point in the right dirrection.

```
    while i < 20 {
        let bubbleSize = self.frame.width / 12
        let bubble = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: bubbleSize)

        let widthL = -self.frame.size.width / 2 + bubble.frame.size.width / 2 
        let widthH = self.frame.size.width / 2 - bubble.frame.size.width / 2 

        let heightL = -self.frame.size.height / 2 + bubble.frame.size.height/ 2 
        let heightH = self.frame.size.height / 2 - bubble.frame.size.height / 2

        var randWidth = randomNumber(range: widthL..<widthH)
        var randHeight = randomNumber(range: heightL..<heightH)

        bubble.fillColor = SKColor.cyan
        bubble.position = CGPoint(x: randWidth, y: randHeight)

        self.addChild(bubble)
 }

func randomNumber(range: Range<CGFloat>) -> CGFloat {
    //function that gives a random number of a range of CGFloats entered
    let min = range.lowerBound
    let max = range.upperBound
    return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(CGFloat(max - min)))) + min
}
```

Comment: How about using the CGRect `Intersects` function, checking the  frame of the node you are placing against every other node to see if there is an overlap?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. It essentially divides the screen into a grid and places the bubbles in grid locations while ensuring no other bubble is at that position. there is lots more you could do with this, like add slight random placement to the location (random generate some small offsets -2 to +2 for x and y values so that they don't look so perfectly placed).

```
let bubbleSize = self.frame.width / 12
let minX = 0 - self.frame.size.width / 2
let maxX = self.frame.size.width / 2
let minY = 0 - self.frame.size.height/ 2
let maxY = self.frame.size.height/ 2
var usedIndexes: [Int]!
let xRange = maxX * 2
let yRange = maxY * 2
let cols = xRange / bubbleSize
let rows = yRange / bubbleSize

func createBubbles(count: Int) {

    for _ in 0..<count {
        createBubble()
    }
}

func createBubble() {

    let index = findSlot()
    let posX = index % cols 
    let posY = index / cols
    let bubble = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: bubbleSize)
    bubble.fillColor = SKColor.cyan
    bubble.position = CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY)
    self.addChild(bubble)
}

func findSlot() -> Int {

    //preventative measure to stop endless loop from happening
    guard usedIndexes.count > rows * cols else { return 0 }

    let randomX = randomNumber(range: 0..<cols)
    let randomY = randomNumber(range: 0..<rows)

    let index = randomX + randomY * cols 
    if usedIndexes.contains(index) {
        return findSlot()
    }
    else {
        usedIndexes.append(index)
    }

    return index
}
```

Comment: Is this going to give fairly fixed layouts, with the screen effectively a chessboard-like structure with nodes only in each square?

Comment: @SteveIves that's why I threw in the bit about (random generate some small offsets -2 to +2 for x and y values so that they don't look so perfectly placed) . There is potentially way less looping doing it this way than using the `intersects` or `contains` funcs. Ultimately we're both just guessing at the OP needs because they really have not supplied enough information to say one way is better than the other or which way might work better for them. The `intersects` and `contains` funcs might seem an obvious choice but this might be just outside the box enough to work for them.

Comment: Agreed - if he supplied a drawing of his ideal layout... another way would be to add physics bodies to everything with suitable collision detection, place everything and le the physics engine move them and then remove the physics bodies.